# Autenticação OAuth com Guzzle PHP

Tags: php, oauth, guzzle

Estou integrando um sistema via API e para isso preciso me autenticar a mesma por OAuth, para receber um token de acesso.
Para autorização e recebimento do token estou utilizando a biblioteca Guzzle e passando todas as informações que a empresa do sistema informou, porém me retorna o erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://api.si9sistemas.com.br/imobilsi9-api/oauth/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"code":401,"status":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this feature","timestamp":"2022 (truncated...) in C:\www\complae\guzzle\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0 C:\www\complae\guzzle\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(69): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL, Array, NULL) #1 C:\www\complae\guzzle\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(204): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 C:\www\complae\guzzle\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(153): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL) #3 C:\www\complae\guzzle\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(48): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise: in C:\www\complae\guzzle\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 113
```

O meu script está assim:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.si9sistemas.com.br/imobilsi9-api/oauth/token', [
'auth' => ['user', base64_encode('password')],    
'headers' => [
    'Authorization' => ['Basic chave'],
]
]);
echo $res->getStatusCode();
echo $res->getHeader('content-type')[0];
echo $res->getBody();
```

Nos parâmetros onde coloquei como valores: **user, password e chave** e substitui pelos dados fornecidos pela empresa.

Detalhe: Os mesmos dados passados pelo Postman, me retorna o token que preciso, porém com o PHP não consigo.

Configurações do Postman:

[Parâmetros Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhfT0.png)

[Headers Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm7aq.png)

Algum parâmetro necessário que tenha passado em branco?

Comment: Tenta colocar a resposta do Postman, e todo log de erro do GuzzleHttp, acho que fica mais claro, já que não é possível simular o seu caso devido as chaves, mas só por encargo duvida tenta retornar assim, `var_dump(json_decode($res->getBody(), true));`

Comment: @Bulfaitelo o erro é muito extenso. É viável postá-lo completo na pergunta?

Comment: sim formatando direito ajuda-a leitura, também posta a imagem do Postman, e oculta os dados sensíveis.

Comment: @Bulfaitelo alterei a pergunta como solicitado

Comment: Vou responder com um teste vê se tem uma resposta diferente de 401.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Usando como base o que já funciona no Postman, consegui o seguinte código abaixo:

```
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.si9sistemas.com.br/imobilsi9-api/oauth/token', [
    'query' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => 'xxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxx',

    ],
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Basic chave',
    ]
    ]);
    echo $res->getStatusCode();
    echo $res->getHeader('content-type')[0];
    echo $res->getBody();
```

Substitua os 'xxxx' e o "basic Chave" pelos parâmetros que você tem.
Não precisa criptografar a senha porque ela está sendo enviada via post, (a não ser que o esperado seja ela já criptografada (que é incomum).

Os dados estão sendo enviados via [Query string](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters) (direto na url).

Geralmente acesso via OAuth é por token de acesso, mas não sei se esses sistema em questão tem habilitado.

Comment: Fiz as alterações e retornou o token desejado.
Instanciei a classe da seguinte maneira  new GuzzleHttp\Client()
Vou marcar a sua resposta como solução.
Obrigado.

Comment: @Zaiyt, Isso ai, perdão eu costumo usar o `use GuzzleHttp\Client;` no inicio do código ai não precisa colocar ele completo para instanciar.